# Create external reference id

Tags: odoo

I have duplicated a new group in OpenERP 6.1.1 .
Now I need to create an external reference id for it since I need to refer it in a view.

Normally, I guess, I should have created the group using an xml file but now I have already been using the group and assigned users to it so I don't wan't to redo the whole thing again.

Is there a simpler way ? Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually insert a row in the table `ir_model_data`. `name` is the external id and `res_id` is integer id. Other required fields are `module` and `model`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so but wasn't clear whether it may break something.